# Recursive Aggregate in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The simplified version of the schema I'm working with looks like this:

Nodes:

```
Id Name   ParentId
0  Parent NULL
1  Child1 0
2  Child2 0
```

Attributes:

```
Id NodeId Value
0  1      1
1  1      2
```

So a Node can have many Nodes as Children and a Node can also have many attributes.

I want to create a view which maps a Node's Id to the MAX Value of all its attributes and the attributes of all its children. So for the sample data above, the view should contain:

```
Id Value
0  2
1  2
2  NULL
```

I've tried various things with CTEs, but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide next levels of example data and your expected results... Just to make sure the problem statement

Comment: What happens to value 1 for ID 0?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy Nothing, I think, since the value for its child is greater.

Comment: Correct, the largest value wins, so if a child has an attribute with greater Value than the parent's attributes, the parent's Id in the view should map to the child's attribute's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
;with nodeAttributes as (
    select n.Id, n.Name, n.ParentId, a.Value
    from Nodes n
    left outer join Attributes a on n.Id = a.NodeId
),
cte as
(
    select n.Id, n.Name, n.Id RootId, n.ParentId, n.Value
    from nodeAttributes n

    union all

    select n.Id, n.Name, c.RootId, n.ParentId, n.Value
    from nodeAttributes n
    join cte c on c.Id = n.ParentId
)

select n.Id,  x.maxValue
from Nodes n
join (select RootId, max(Value) maxValue
      from cte
      group by RootId) x on x.RootId = n.Id
```